# Geometry of the pentachloridoindate(III) anion

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecular-structure, halides

According to Brown *et al.*,<sup>1</sup> the crystal structure of $\ce{[NEt4]2[InCl5]}$ reveals that the pentachloridoindate(III) anion, $\ce{[InCl5]^2-}$, adopts a square pyramidal $C_\mathrm{4v}$ geometry (VSEPR theory would predict trigonal bipyramidal $D_\mathrm{3h}$):

[image: Crystal structure of [NEt4]2[InCl5], ref 1]

According to Greenwood and Earnshaw,<sup>2</sup>

> It will be noted that $\ce{[InCl5]^2-}$ is not isostructural with the isoelectronic species $\ce{[SnCl5]-}$ and $\ce{SbCl5}$, which have the more common $D_\mathrm{3h}$ symmetry. […] $\ce{[NEt4]2[TlCl5]}$ is isomorphous with $\ce{[NEt4]2[InCl5]}$ and presumably has a similar structure for the anion.

However, the structure of $\ce{[PPh4]2[InCl5].MeCN}$ was reported to have the usual trigonal bipyramidal structure for the anion,<sup>3</sup> which throws a spanner in the works. I can't understand much of the paper as it's in German. Since it's a report of a crystal structure, though, I don't really expect it to say much about the chemistry of the compound.

Can the reported differences in molecular geometry here be rationalised?

---

*References*

1. Brown, D. S.; Einstein, F. W. B.; Tuck, D. G. Tetragonal-pyramidal indium(III) species. Crystal structure of tetraethylammonium pentachloroindate(III). *Inorg. Chem.* **1969,** *8* (1), 14–18. [DOI: 10.1021/ic50071a004](https://doi.org/10.1021/ic50071a004).
2. Greenwood, N. N.; Earnshaw, A. *Chemistry of the Elements,* 2nd ed.; Butterworth–Heinemann: Oxford, U.K., 1997, p 238.
3. Bubeinheim, W.; Frenzen, G.; Müller, U. Die Chloroindate $\ce{[PPh4]2[In2Cl6]}$ und $\ce{[PPh4]2[InCl5].CH3CN}$. *Acta Crystallogr., Sect. C: Cryst. Struct. Commun.* **1995,** *51,* 1120–1124. [DOI: 10.1107/S0108270194011789](https://doi.org/10.1107/S0108270194011789).

Comment: Do you have a CIF-file from [Brown1969]by any chance? In addition to [Bubenheim1995] I've just found three more recent crystal structures with nearly perfect trigonal bipyramidal $D_\mathrm{3h}$ geometry of $\ce{[InCl5]^{2-}}$ and it looks like the Brown's work is the only featuring square pyramid. I wonder whether it has something to do with the experimental data or refinement at that time -- $R$-factor of nearly 10% seems quite lousy for such a simple small-molecule structure.

Comment: @andselisk no cif, sorry. I guess that might be a possibility, although I don't know much about crystallography to begin with - so I'm happy to hear any thoughts on the matter.

Comment: Well, having a look at the structure with checkcif.iucr.org is where I would start. As I said, $R$-factor might be a bit off due to the wrong initial symmetry and it might cause the wrong structure, especially if there is a proposed disorder (according to the paper). I cannot find the data in CCDC either, though the entry exists. Weird, maybe it's just me doing something wrong.

Comment: Related: [Use of geometry index for the determination of coordination environment](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/80604/use-of-geometry-index-for-the-determination-of-coordination-environment)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**TL;DR** Initially published crystal structure of $\ce{[NEt4]2[InCl5]}$ [1] according to the further investigations [3], is not valid. The $\ce{InCl5^2-}$ ion does not have $C_\mathrm{4v}$ symmetry, and VSEPR theory pretty much explains formation of numerous slightly distorted trigonal bipyramidal $\ce{InCl5^2-}$-containing complexes according to the most recent single-crystal structure experiments.

From the other side, the bond lengths and geometry index refer to the dominating character of *square pyramidal environment*, which is in this case can be dictated by the crystal packing, towards which $\ce{[InCl5]^2-}$ is more sensible than $\ce{[SnCl5]-}$ due to the noticeable size difference ($\ce{[InCl5]^2-}$ is bulkier). Either way, it looks like another crystallographic experiment (preferably at lower temperatures to decrease the size of thermal ellipsoids) is needed to determine the angles more precisely.

As a general advice, always pay attention to the $R_1$ and $R_2$ values of the crystal structure. A rule of thumb: a good structure refinement of small molecules should lead to $R_1 < 0.05$ and $R_2 < 0.12$.

---

Crystal structure of $\ce{[NEt4]2[InCl5]}$, determined in 1969 [1], has been subsequently criticized in several publications, mainly involving additional symmetry vibration analysis of Raman spectra for $\ce{MX5^2-}$ anions [2]. It's been established that $\ce{InCl5^2-}$ ion does not have $C_\mathrm{4v}$ symmetry (but retains $C_\mathrm{2v}$), and that the crystal may not be centrosymmetric.

The results are summarized in [3]:

[image]

> Deconvolution of the single-crystal data was again performed with the aid 
>   of the low temperature data, revealing $11$ $\ce{InCl5^2-}$ bands between $300$ and $\pu{100 cm-1}$. Two overlapping A stretches are clearly evident at $292$ and $\pu{286 cm-1}$, but no B stretch is apparent. The two E symmetry stretches expected for the anion of a $C_2$ site, but not for a $C_4$ site, are evident at $281$ and $\pu{271 cm-1}$. [...] With the aid of low-temperature data, the four E modes predicted for $\ce{InCl5^2-}$ at $C_2$ sites are found at $144$, $136$, $122$, and $\pu{103 cm-1}$ in the single-crystal data. With this reinterpretation of the spectrum it is no longer necessary to assume arbitrarily the presence of a lattice mode in this region.
>
> In summary, the vibrational data for the tetraethylammonium salts of $\ce{InCl5^2-}$ and $\ce{TlCl5^2-}$ indicate that these complexes reside on sites lacking full $C_4$ symmetry. The most straightforward conclusion from the vibrational data is that the $\ce{InCl5^2-}$ ions have local $C_2$ symmetry, which would be inconsistent with the previous structure determination [1]. [...]
>
> The structure of $\ce{[(C2H5)4N]2[InCl5]}$, as previously reported, consisted of centrosymmetrically related $\ce{InCl5^2-}$ ions situated about the 
>   Wyckoff c positions of $C_4$ symmetry in space group $C_\mathrm{4h}-P4/n$. 
>   Coaxial with the $\ce{InCl5^2-}$ ions are disordered $\ce{(C2H5)4N+}$ ions 
>   also situated about the Wyckoff c positions. The N atoms of the two remaining $\ce{(C2H5)4N+}$ ions in the unit cell occupy the centrosymmetrically related Wyckoff b sites of $S_4$ symmetry, the cation as a whole again being disordered. **There are two disturbing features of this solution and its subsequent refinement: the disorder of the $\ce{(C2H5)4N+}$ ions and the significant residual electron density in the region of the basal Cl atoms of the tetragonal-pyramidal anion**.

It is demonstrated further that for the ordered model the most satisfying crystallographic interpretation coexists with $C_2$ rather than $C_4$ symmetry. A correlation of allowed point symmetries implies switching from $P4/n$ to $P\bar{4}$ space group, thus reducing $R$-factor ($R_1$) from $9.5\%$ to $6.7\%$.

> During the refinement in $P\bar{4}$, **small but significant changes 
>   occur in the basal plane of the $\ce{InCl5^2-}$ ion**. The basal Cl atoms 
>   have moved by $\pu{-0.5 A}$ from their fourfold symmetric positions in $P4/n$, leading to variations in the bond distances and angles about the In atom (Figure 3) that are qualitatively sufficient to explain the vibrational results.

[image]

[Geometry index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry_index) $\tau_5$ for $\ce{[InCl5]}$ fragment can be used to determine formal coordination environment as follows:

$$\tau_5 = \frac{\beta - \alpha}{60^\circ},$$

where $\alpha$, $\beta$ - two greatest valence angles of the coordination center ($\angle \ce{Cl - In - Cl}$, $\alpha < \beta$).

\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\tau_5 &= 0 \qquad &\text{square pyramidal geometry} \\
\tau_5 &= 1 \qquad &\text{trigonal bipyramidal geometry}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

For the original $\ce{[NEt4]2[InCl5]}$ structure refined in [3] I've taken angular values from their [supplementary materials](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/suppl/10.1021/ic50150a011/suppl_file/ic50150a011_si_001.pdf). It turned out that changing space group to $P\bar{4}$ still results in dominating character of **square pyramidal geometry** of $\ce{[InCl5]^2-}$, though one must remember that the rotation axis of highest order is $C_2$, not $C_4$:

$$\alpha = (150.6 \pm 5.0)^\circ, \beta = (154.1 \pm 6.0)^\circ, \bar{\tau_5} = \frac{154.1^\circ - 150.6^\circ}{60^\circ} = 0.06; \tau_5 \in [0.04; 0.24]$$

Paper [4] mentions that for isoelectronic $\ce{[SnCl5]-}$-contining structures with various cations only trigonal-bipyramidal geometries were reported, and suggests higher influence of crystal packing on $\ce{[InCl5]^2-}$ geometry. This can also be explained by higher flexibility of $\ce{MX5}$ fragment in $\ce{[PPh4]2[InCl5]}$ in comparison with $\ce{[PPh4][SnCl5]}$ [5] due to greater average bond length: $d(\ce{In - Cl}) = \pu{2.5 A}$, $d(\ce{Sn - Cl}) = \pu{2.3 A}$.

As for auxiliary experimental data, all crystal structures including $\ce{[InCl5]^2-}$ fragment determined in the past two decade completely support VSEPR theory that predicts trigonal bipyramidal $D_\mathrm{3h}$ symmetry (with one intermediate exception of $\tau_5 \approx 50\%$).

---

1. **bis(Tetraphenylphosphonium) pentachloro-indate(III)** [4], trigonal bipyramidal geometry:
   $$\alpha = 124.24^\circ, \beta = 174.74^\circ, \tau_5 = \frac{174.74^\circ - 124.24^\circ}{60^\circ} = 0.84$$

   $\color{#EEEEEE}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{H}$;
   $\color{#909090}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{C}$;
   $\color{#FF8000}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{P}$;
   $\color{#1FF01F}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{Cl}$;
   $\color{#A67573}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{In}$.

   [image]

---

2. **bis(Diphenyldichlorophosphonium) pentachloro-indate(III)** [6], trigonal bipyramidal geometry:
   $$\alpha = 120.93^\circ, \beta = 179.29^\circ, \tau_5 = \frac{179.29^\circ - 120.93^\circ}{60^\circ} = 0.97$$

   $\color{#EEEEEE}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{H}$;
   $\color{#909090}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{C}$;
   $\color{#FF8000}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{P}$;
   $\color{#1FF01F}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{Cl}$;
   $\color{#A67573}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{In}$.

   [image]

---

3. **tetrakis($\mu_3$-Selenido)-tetrakis($\mu_2$-1,5-bis(diphenylphosphino)pentane)-deca-gold(I) pentachloro-indate(III)** [7], intermediate geometry:
   $$\alpha = 138.45^\circ, \beta = 166.50^\circ, \tau_5 = \frac{166.50^\circ - 138.45^\circ}{60^\circ} = 0.47$$

   $\color{#EEEEEE}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{H}$;
   $\color{#909090}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{C}$;
   $\color{#FF8000}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{P}$;
   $\color{#1FF01F}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{Cl}$;
   $\color{#FFA100}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{Se}$;
   $\color{#A67573}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{In}$;
   $\color{#FFD123}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{Au}$.

   [image]

---

4. **tetrakis($\mu_2$-chloro)-chloro-tetrakis(triphenylphosphine-P)-di-copper(I)-indium(III) tetrahydrofuran solvate** [8], trigonal bipyramidal geometry (though authors refer to it as to "quasi square-pyramidal" coordination based on a single slightly shorter $\ce{In - Cl}$ bond distance $(d(\ce{In-Cl_\mathrm{ap}}) = \pu{2.36 A})$, shortest $d(\ce{In-Cl_\mathrm{eq}}) = \pu{2.42 A})$: 
   $$\alpha = 123.90^\circ, \beta = 172.89^\circ, \tau_5 = \frac{172.89^\circ - 123.90^\circ}{60^\circ} = 0.82$$

   $\color{#EEEEEE}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{H}$;
   $\color{#909090}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{C}$;
   $\color{#FF8000}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{P}$;
   $\color{#1FF01F}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{Cl}$;
   $\color{#C88033}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{Cu}$;
   $\color{#A67573}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{In}$.

   [image]

---

#### Bibliography

1. Brown, D. S.; Einstein, F. W. B.; Tuck, D. G. *Inorganic Chemistry* **1969**, 8 (1), 14–18. DOI [10.1021/ic50071a004](https://doi.org/10.1021/ic50071a004).
2. Adams, D. M.; Smardzewski, R. R. *Journal of the Chemical Society A: Inorganic, Physical, Theoretical* **1971**, 714. DOI [10.1039/j19710000714](https://doi.org/10.1039/j19710000714).
3. Joy, G.; Gaughan, A. P.; Wharf, I.; Shriver, D. F.; Dougherty, J. P. *Inorganic Chemistry* **1975**, 14 (8), 1795–1801. DOI [10.1021/ic50150a011](https://doi.org/10.1021/ic50150a011).
4. Bubenheim, W.; Frenzen, G.; Müller, U. *Acta Crystallographica Section C* **1995**, 51 (6), 1120–1124. DOI [10.1107/S0108270194011789](https://doi.org/10.1107/s0108270194011789).
5. Müller, U.; Siekmann, J. F. *Acta Cryst C* **1996**, 52 (2), 330–333. DOI [10.1107/S0108270195011073](https://doi.org/10.1107/s0108270195011073).
6. Taraba, J.; Zak, Z. *Inorganic Chemistry* **2003**, 42 (11), 3591–3594. DOI [10.1021/ic034091n](https://doi.org/10.1021/ic034091n).
7. Olkowska-Oetzel, J.; Sevillano, P.; Eichhöfer, A.; Fenske, D. *European Journal of Inorganic Chemistry*, **2004** (5), 1100–1106. DOI [10.1002/ejic.200300774](https://doi.org/10.1002/ejic.200300774).
8. Zhang, X.-Z.; Song, Y.-W.; HuiWu, F.; Zhang, Q.-F. *Zeitschrift für Naturforschung B* **2007**, 62 (6). DOI [10.1515/znb-2007-0605](https://doi.org/10.1515/znb-2007-0605).

Comment: Certainly not the answer I expected - but excellent nonetheless. Thank you!

Comment: @orthocresol I don't know what was wrong with me last night, but I calculated $\tau_5$ for your complex wrongly (improper $\alpha$ from SI), my sincere apologies. It actually supports square pyramidal geometry even for the structure refined for the second time, though due to lowered symmetry one cannot attribute $C_\mathrm{4v}$. I edited the answer correspondingly adding a few more details. Probably you might want to unmark it as accepted (or even downvote), as new experimental data or QC-calculations could be more significant that the idea of crystal packing effect proposed here.

Comment: No problem. Well, generally, if new information comes in, the accepted answer can always be changed, so IMO it's not much of a big deal. Downvoting would be cruel, no? ;)

Comment: @orthocresol Well, it still was my fault and the faults should be punished/ignored, not rewarded. But thank you for the nice attitude!